# Volume of entire app gets quieter after accessing mic

Tags: ios, swift, volume, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I am having a volume issue within my iOS app.  When I call `setupMic()` the volume level of the entire app is lowered significantly.
Here is the code I am using:

```
func setupMic() {
    //make an AudioSession, set it to PlayAndRecord and make it active
    let audioSession: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch {
       print("There was an error setting the category")
    }
    do {
       try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
       print("There was an error setting the audio session to active")
    }


    //set up the URL for the audio file
    let documents: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let str = documents.stringByAppendingPathComponent("recordTest.caf")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(str as String)

    //make a dictionary to hold the recording setting so we can instantiate our AVAudioRecorder
    let number = NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4)
    let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [AVFormatIDKey: number,
                                                 AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
                                                 AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                                                 AVEncoderBitRateKey: 12800,
                                                 AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
                                                 AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Min.rawValue]

    //Instantiate an AVAudioRecorder
    do {
        recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: url, settings: recordSettings)
    } catch {
      print("There was an error")
    }
}

//This function is called everytime our timer levelTimer fires
func levelTimerCallback() {
    recorder.updateMeters()
    let averagePower = self.recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0)
    if averagePower > -7 {
        stopMonitoring()

        print(recorder.peakPowerForChannel(0))
        didCompleteChallenge(true)
    }
}

func startMonitoring() {
    if self.recorder != nil {
        recorder.prepareToRecord()
        recorder.meteringEnabled = true
        //start recording
        recorder.record()
        //instantiate a timer to be called with whatever frequency we want to grab metering values
        self.levelTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(levelTimerCallback), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func stopMonitoring() {
    self.recorder.stop()
    self.recorder.deleteRecording()
    self.levelTimer.invalidate()
}
```

I call `setupMic()` and `startMonitoring()` in an `updateWith()` method.  I also call `stopMonitoring()` when the view is updated again with the `updateWith()`
Once the microphone is accessed the volume decreases.  Any suggestions? Any fixes?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the issue.  The volume was not actually getting quieter, the audio was actually routing to the earpiece.  I just needed to set the audio session category options to .DefaultToSpeaker.  `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [.DefaultToSpeaker])`.  Thanks anyway internet.

Comment: I set this category, but when I plug my earphones, I got to know that only one side got sound, other side not working, any clue ?